# How to properly refresh packaged dlls for MSI with VS Setup/Installer Project after Nuget update?

Tags: windows-installer, visual-studio-setup-proje

I have updated nuget packages but the Setup project in my solution is not updating. I rebuild everything and then if I do the file difference between bin/release project and folder output folder (results after installing the MSI), the files are different, msi one still using old dlls.

Tried Setup > Detect Dependencies > (right-click) Refresh dependencies
but it made no difference